# Нужно перевести число unsigned long 8948550000441f0f в 10-ую СС? (программа)

Tags: c, ubuntu

В переменной `unsigned long` хранится значение `8948550000441f0f`
Как перевести `8948550000441f0f` в 10-ую систему счисления? Нужен именно код

Comment: `9892250040012119823` [тынц](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html)

Comment: мне нужен код, а не просто онлайн переводчик

Comment: если оно и так в лонге, то зачем его переводить? или оно текстом вводится?

Comment: мне нужно перевести значение этой переменной в 10-ую систему счисления и вывести в файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

unsigned long v = 0x8948550000441f0f;
printf("%lu", v);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: в %d не вмещается  0x8948550000441f0f
Должно быть: 9892250040012119823
Выводит: 4464399

Comment: `%lu`  - точно ж!

Comment: все работает, спасибо большое!

Comment: галочка у ответа слева ;)

Comment: нажал, спасибо !:)